# How to view data coming into App Scripts web app

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, post, web-applications

There is an issue with the data coming into my Google Apps Script web app from a webhook but I don’t understand how to view it.
This is basically what I have:

```
function doPost(incomingData){
    console.log(incomingData.postData.contents)
}
```

I have the script attached to a standard GCP project. I was hoping to see incomingData in Cloud logs but I do not see anything in the section where I usually spot console log data.

Thanks!

Comment: What steps do you followed to deploy your web app? Do you saved a new version after the last edit you made to it?

Comment: Hi Nutritional, be aware of that if you are invoking the script out of the head, console is ignored. I mean, if you post to an /exec ending url, console will not work (it will in a /dev ending). My very cheesy solution is to write the debugging information into any spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks jpp, I ended up sending the debugging info to a Google Doc :)